# Close pyqt5 app if user rejects the configuration dialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to create an app to interact with Yandex Disk API (Cloud storage) but have been failed with settings window.

Here is settings dialog:

```
class SettingsUI(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.settings = QSettings('settings.ini', QSettings.IniFormat)

        self.toolButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.lineEdit_watcher_folder.setText(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()))

    def isFirstRun(self):
        return True if self.settings.value('first_run') is None else False

    def getAPIKey(self):
        return self.settings.value('api_key')

    def getFolder(self):
        return self.settings.value('folder')

    def getWhitelistExtensions(self):
        return self.settings.value('files_extension')

    def getMailError(self):
        return self.settings.value('mail_error')

    def accept(self):
        if not self.lineEdit_API.text():
            QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Ошибка', 'Укажите API ключ для доступа к Yandex API')
        elif not self.lineEdit_watcher_folder.text() or not os.path.isdir(self.lineEdit_watcher_folder.text()):
            QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Ошибка', 'Укажите папку с файлами для загрузки')
        elif not self.lineEdit_allowed_ext.text():
            QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Ошибка', 'Не указаны форматы файлов')
        else:
            self.settings.setValue('first_run', False)
            self.settings.setValue('api_key', self.lineEdit_API.text())
            self.settings.setValue('folder', self.lineEdit_watcher_folder.text())
            self.settings.setValue('files_extension', tuple(self.lineEdit_allowed_ext.text().split(';')))
            self.settings.setValue('mail_error', self.lineEdit_mail_error.text())

            super().accept()
```

Here is the main code:

```
class MainUI(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setupTopMenu()
        self.firstRun()
        self.show()

    def setupTopMenu(self):
        self.settingsDialog = SettingsUI()
        self.settings_menu.triggered.connect(self.settingsDialog.exec)
        self.quit_menu.triggered.connect(self.shutdown)

    def shutdown(self):  # TODO method for correctly shutdown threads
        # sys.exit()
        qApp.quit()  

    def firstRun(self):
        if self.settingsDialog.isFirstRun():
            if self.settingsDialog.exec() == QDialog.Rejected:
                self.shutdown()


class WorkerNewTask(QObject):...


class WorkerYandexArchive(QObject):...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_ui = MainUI()
    # main_ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I would like to close app if user cancels the settings window in the first run but when interpreter is reaches qApp.quit() in shutdown method, the app is still working.

At the same time if I click on quit_menu button in top menu, which connected to shutdown method, it'll close app.

If someone can tell me what I did wrong I would be glad :).
Kind regards, Maxim

Comment: Can you tell where and when qApp is initialized?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure but I think it's initialized when I create object app from class QApplication. I tried QApplication.instance() instead of qApp, but it don't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that application is not completely initialized at that point. Note the calls chain: `MainUI() -> MainUI.__init__() -> MainUI.first_run() -> MainUI.settingsDialog.exec() -> MainUI.shutdown() -> qApp.quit()`. However, in `__name__ == '__main__'` part of the script the code continues with `app.exec()`. So it might be that `app` is simply not initialized yet when `quit()` is called.

Comment: Thanks, found this in Qt docs:
After this function has been called, the application leaves the main event loop and returns from the call to exec(). The exec() function returns returnCode. If the event loop is not running, this function does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this would be to just close the window and set the application to close when the last window closes

```
def shutdown(self):
    QApplication.instance().setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(True)
    self.close()
```

Comment: Same result :(. quitOnLastWindowClosed is True by default on my PyQt 5.5.1